# What is the advantage of having a .bss section?

Tags: c

What is the benefit of having 2 sections - .data and .bss for process scope variables. Why not just have one? I know what each section is used for. I am using gcc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.bss consumes "memory" but not space within the executable file. Its sole purpose is to hold zero-initialized data (as you know).

.data (and related sections such as rodata) do actually consume space within the executable file, and usually holds strings, integers, and perhaps even entire objects.

There is a lot of zero-initialized data in a typical program, so having that data not consume extra space in the output file is a significant bonus.

As for the multiple .*data sections... .rodata/.data can be used as a hint for memory protection (disallow overwriting .rodata, allow read/write to .data).

Comment: Can you please give some examples? Memory view, asm instructions etc.

Comment: @Bruce: at runtime, there's basically no difference between .data and .bss. The difference is in the linker output (one section exists on disk, the other doesn't), and in how the executable loader loads the section. .data is a copy - the loader might use memcpy... .bss is zeroed - the loader might use memset.